# Alternative to postfix with SNI certificates + Dovecot compatibility

Tags: postfix, dovecot

As we're aware postfix doesn't support SNI (Server Name Indication), which means that if you'd define a certificate, it will be used for all domain names that you have on that server, which could be bad for people not willing to pay big bucks to purchase fancy certificates. Postfix states on their website that they have no plans to implement SNI.

I have my mail server configured with Dovecot and Postfix. I would like to replace postfix with something that supports SNI and compatible with Dovecot (or at least accepts the same username/password database scheme from Dovecot).

Could you please tell me what alternatives to postfix exist that fulfill these conditions (preferably open source).

Comment: Can you explain the scenario where a single certificate for a single name would not suffice in the context of smtps? I think that scenario is unclear at best and I would assume this is the reason why it's not supported.

Comment: Hi, why do you need SNI support for your smtpd? The only thing that needs to match for ssl verification is the CN on the ssl cert matches the banner hostname. SSL certificates are so ridiculously cheap now-a-days (<50 USD/year) I find your argument is hard to accept.

Comment: Further, your reverse DNS ptr must match your banner hostname for many mail services to not reject you outright as a spammer.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Thank you for your response. A single certificate for a single name (domain) is fine. But I have a server that runs multiple domains.

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek Thank you for your response. I need my smtp connection to be encrypted for security, but I don't want e-mail clients to complain about certificates.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist But for smtp w/ TLS the certificate would be for the *mail server name*, not all domain names that the mail server deals with.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Maybe it's my ignorance that's making me look for a strange solution to someone well-informed like you. Let me try to explain the situation: I have a mail server, which can be reached with two domains mail.mydomain.com and mail.mydomain2.com. How do I secure those connections without having certificates problems? Please explain.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist http://serverfault.com/questions/389413/what-host-name-should-the-ssl-certificate-for-an-smtp-server-contain seems to cover this subject

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Lemme try to understand the siutaion after reading your comments and reading the article in the link there. When you say the *mail server name*, you mean the mx record of the domain. So if I got to thunderbird and write that I want my smtp server to be mail.myweb.com:25, it will completely ignore this information for the certificate, and will only use the myweb.com's mx record and confirm the certificate with that. Is that right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you already know all the FQDN's you are going to need, buy a SAN-certificate.

If you need to be flexible with you certificates you can try and setup a nginx smtp proxy. I looked at the documentation and from the looks it should support SNI but it's not going to be an easy setup I think:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_ssl_module.html

**1st update:**
two links that might help you:
http://citrin.ru/nginx:ngx_mail_core_module
http://wiki.nginx.org/MailCoreModule

**2nd update:**
As of 2016 you can easily get SAN certificates from the [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) Project for **free**.

I strongly suggest, you get yourself a SAN certificate and include all the FQDN you need for your service in that one certificate. Currently you can include as many as 100 subject alternative names per certificate.

Comment: nginx is a good idea but it's not for free, is it?

Comment: nginx is free, see: http://nginx.org/LICENSE

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of your endeavour? Do you need multiple FQDN's for your clients being able to connecting securely to different hostnames or for the smtpd delivering it?

Comment: Yes! I have multiple domains and I want my clients not to hear certificate complaints when sending e-mails.

Comment: Do your clients really need to use their domain when delivering mail to the MTA? To my knowledge there is no reason why not to buy one cheap certificate for a FQDN unrelated to any of your customers. For delivery the RFC's state that **any** certificate should be accepted because even the lack of STARTTLS should not cause your mail to bounce. So the only reason that remains is your customers really wanting to use their domain in the settings of their client. Something once set up, never shows up again.

Comment: Yes, my clients need to use their domain. I'm avoiding purchasing certificates because I'm looking for the most economical solution right now. I still will try nginx and see if it helps, but I'm over swamped  with stuff to do right now and I had a time window of doing this when I wrote the post.

Comment: Hi there again. Could you please assist me in configuring nginx for mail smtp reverse proxy? I've been working on this for days and I there are things I don't understand that are not explained in any tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the answer.